# How do I display console log in electron app

Tags: electron

I'm currently creating a JS Desktop App using Electron. I'm able to get everything functional how I want it, but I want to be able to update the users on certain tasks and also display errors in the app itself.

Is there any way to add a section (terminal if you will) or something similar inside the UI, so I can log things out to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Providing application feedback to your user is as simple as having a `statusUpdate` function in your main process `send`
a message (via your `preload.js` script) to your render process. Within your render process, listen for a message on the
assigned channel and once received, update the content of your DOM element.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
    statusTest();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

function statusTest() {
    let counter = 1;
    let message;

    setInterval(() => {
        statusUpdate(`Status message ${counter} from main process.`);
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
}

function statusUpdate(message) {
    window.webContents.send('statusMessage', message);
}
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From main to render
        statusMessage: (message) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('statusMessage', message);
        }
    }
);
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="status">Status: </label>
        <textarea id="status" cols="40" rows="10" disabled></textarea>
    </body>

    <script>
        let status = document.getElementById('status');

        window.ipcRenderer.statusMessage((event, message) => {
            status.value += message + '\n'; // Append message
            status.scrollTop = status.scrollHeight; // Show last entry
        });
    </script>
</html>
```